# Why the request is not getting dropped in node js?

Tags: node.js, http, request, response

```
//
// const app = express();
// console.log(8)
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req,res) =>{

   const t1 = Date.now();

   while((Date.now() - t1)/1000 <= 60) {

   }
   res.end('hello');
   console.log('hiiii');
});

server.listen(3003,()=>{console.log('server is up')});
```

If I do 5 curl localhost:3003 , I see hiii gets printed in gap of 1 minute,so 5 hii will be printed each in gap of 1 minute, my question is since the single thread of nodejs was busy in while loop ,why the other 4 curl request didn't get drop, what queued them up inspite of the single thread of node was busy serving first request

Comment: That's a good question, I added a log after `const t1` to see whether the other requests would at least reach that point, and it didn't, so I suppose that the other request are handing in a level bellow the application, and they are queued there.

Answer (score 0):

> The Event Loop is what allows Node.js to perform non-blocking I/O
> operations despite the fact that JavaScript is single-threaded by
> offloading operations to the system kernel whenever possible. Since
> most modern kernels are multi-threaded, they can handle multiple
> operations executing in the background. When one of these operations
> completes, the kernel tells Node.js so that the appropriate callback
> may be added to the poll queue to eventually be executed.

I suggest to you to read the [full documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/).